# Any CSS resources for printing?

Tags: css, print

Is there any resource like http://www.csszengarden.com/ for Print stylesheets?

I'd like to write some CSS formatted text on a printed media (internal business documentation) with an elegant style, but it looks like there is no help out there.

I don't need LaTeX/TeX typesetting - I'd like to have something more portable and lightweight almost as plain text, with little or no compiling environment.

Answer (score 1):

Print stylesheets are really custom based on your content. Ideally, you want to strip off any fancy items and make sure the page is printing black text on a white background.

The CSS Zen garden is displaying how to use the same content but with different stylesheets to make it appear different. Ideally they would probably all use the same print.css file since their structure and content remains the same.

Comment: Not all books are printed with the same style, font, colors and margins, though. CSS3 has printing directives like margins and such. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/ is all about typography issues. (Maybe this is not the right place to ask, but where then?)

Comment: Ahh okay I understand what you're asking. Unfortunately no I think this feature isn't something heavily utilized yet so I'm not aware of any communities that are trading set print styles for specific content layouts. Also this being only a working draft it's not supported fully yet by anyone. If this standard is adopted hopefully someone does create a simple plugin to analyze code in say the 960 grid system for an easy printing style.